# Has this site a future?

Tags: discussion

According to [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46400/ebooks) the stats of this site are abysmal:
[image]

Meta seems to dead as well with three questions in the last twelve months.

And the last message to chat was posted 497 days ago.

Anybody still around?

Comment: The last number (visits/day) is wrong and should be ignored: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51

Comment: Note that SO has indicated that beta sites will not be shut down just because they aren't ready to leave beta. These stats aren't great, but they don't indicate a lost cause, either.

Comment: I still have the feeling that we are loosing momentum.
Question are dripping in more or less constantly, but community engagement sadly disappeared. Answers are also mostly coming from new users. (This might just be a subjective feeling)

Comment: That's what I wanted to ask. I asked about it in [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312500/393718).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stats are even worse now with just 0.1 questions per day.  I suspect this lowest possible value that can be displayed, so it may be overrated.

I just went through the review queues and found things 14 days old still waiting to be reviewed.

[I see](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) one Mod who seems to visit regularly and two that have not been to the main site in about 2 weeks.  [Looking at Meta](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) one Mod was here last month, one in July 2018, and one not since Mar of 2017